# R apply: using element indices in the function

Tags: r, apply

I have a three dimensional data structure reflecting data at particular longitudes, latitudes, and depth. I would like to **apply** a function to this data. Normally, say I want to find the depth-averaged value I'd do the following:

```
apply(MyData, MAR = c(1, 2), mean)
```

which makes sense to me. What I'm struggling with is that I have want to **apply** a function that depends on longitude and latitude. Is there a way for **apply** to pass the indices of elements to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `outer()` and take advantage of lexical scoping 
so that you don't have to pass myData to the function being 
called with the longitude and lattitude:

```
myData <- read.table(...) # or whatever

outer(seq.int(dim(mydata)[1]),
      seq.int(dim(mydata)[2]),
      function(longitude,lattitude){
        do things that depend on 
            myData[longitude,lattitude,]
      })
```